# Blank product page in admin

Tags: magento-1.9

In ver  1.9.0.1 when I edit any product in the admin the product page is blank and none of the navigation works, except for the dashboard link. I do not get any error, nor do I see any related notices in the system.log or exception.log. The frontend is still functioning properly. Any thoughts about this problem?

Comment: Recently i faced same problem delete var/cache and check

Comment: Make sure you print errors only in php.ini, uncomment in index.php the line which says display_errors